# How to rotate a 2D plot to form a 3D shape?

Tags: plotting

It is common to rotate a plot within its own plane, but how do I rotate a 2D plot along an axis to form a 3D shape?
Say I have the following plot,

```
ParametricPlot[{-Sqrt[x^2 - (x - 1/2)^2], x - 1/2}, {x, 1/2, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

how do I rotate it along the y-axis?

Comment: Look up `RevolutionPlot3D`. Without it, you could achieve the same with `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `RevolutionPlot3D`:

```
f[x_] := Sin[1/x];
ParametricPlot[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```